# Find all collinear of 3 points

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I had a job interview test where the Question is find all Collinear data points of 3 points in a data set.

[wolframalpha.com/input/?i=collinear+lines](https://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=collinear%20lines)

I failed the test but still completed it on my own and could not find any solution that I could understand.

here is the data set

```
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [3, 2], [4, 2], [5, 1]]
```

image of data-set
[image]

The solution should return 6 what it does but I just wanted to know if I got the most optimal solution.

my solution:

```
    /**
     * Will return the amount of lines of 3 points or can made with 3 unique points
     * @param {number} dotsInLine
     *
     *  @returns {number} of lines of 3 points found
     */
    function countLineOf3(dotsInLine) {
        if (dotsInLine === 3) return 1;
        if (dotsInLine > 3) return (dotsInLine - 3) * dotsInLine;
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * will go trough the array of found points on 1 axes and return the count of 3 point lines found
     * @param {array} foundInArr
     * @param {object} matrix
     *
     * @returns {number}
     */
    function foundInAddToCount(foundInArr, matrix) {
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < foundInArr.length; i++) {
            count += countLineOf3(matrix[foundInArr[i]]);
        }

        return count;
    }

    function solution(A) {
        let count = 0;
        let maxX = 0;
        let maxY = 0;
        const xStrait = {};
        const xStraitFound = [];
        const yStrait = {};
        const yStraitFound = [];

        const lineUp = {};
        const lineUpFound = [];
        const lineDown = {};
        const lineDownFound = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (maxX < A[i][0]) maxX = A[i][0];
            if (maxY < A[i][1]) maxY = A[i][1];

            // find strait vertical points
            if (!xStrait[A[i][0]]) xStrait[A[i][0]] = 0;
            xStrait[A[i][0]]++;
            if (xStrait[A[i][0]] === 3) xStraitFound.push(A[i][0]);
            // find strait horizontal points
            if (!yStrait[A[i][1]]) yStrait[A[i][1]] = 0;
            yStrait[A[i][1]]++;
            if (yStrait[A[i][1]] === 3) yStraitFound.push(A[i][1]);

            // find points bottom left to top right
            const x = A[i][0];
            const y = A[i][1];

            const xMinY = x - y;
            const yMinx = y - x;
            //middle line
            let key;
            if (xMinY >= 0 && yMinx >= 0) {
                key = `${xMinY}${yMinx}`;
            } else if (xMinY >= 0 && yMinx < 0) {
                // y zero UP
                key = `${xMinY}0`;
            } else if (xMinY < 0 && yMinx >= 0) {
                // x zero UP
                key = `0${yMinx}`;
            }

            if (key) {
                if (!lineUp[key]) lineUp[key] = 0;
                lineUp[key]++;
                if (lineUp[key] === 3) lineUpFound.push(key);
            }

            const xPlusY = x + y;
            //find points top left to bottom right
            if (!lineDown[`0${xPlusY}`]) lineDown[`0${xPlusY}`] = 0;
            lineDown[`0${xPlusY}`]++;
            if (lineDown[`0${xPlusY}`] === 3) {
                lineDownFound.push(`0${xPlusY}`);
            }
        }

        count += foundInAddToCount(xStraitFound, xStrait);
        count += foundInAddToCount(yStraitFound, yStrait);

        count += foundInAddToCount(lineUpFound, lineUp);
        count += foundInAddToCount(lineDownFound, lineDown);
        return count;
    }

    console.log(
        solution([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [3, 2], [4, 2], [5, 1]])
    );
```

I basically sort all horizontal, vertical and cross lines(sorry I can't find the correct english word) and count them and add them up.

So if anyone has any tips please let me know.

Comment: Please define the problem.  *Why* is the solution `6`?  You said you wanted to find all collinear data points, but your answer is a scalar.

Comment: Also your code doesn't seem to think that [[0,0],[2,1],[4,2]] are collinear

Comment: If you look at this graph https://i.imgur.com/TxvLlux.gif
then make strait lines between 3 points then you can make 6 lines
also [2,1] is not in the data set

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=collinear+lines FYI @Prune

Comment: @MattTimmermans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750359/find-all-collinear-of-3-points#comment103819531_58750359 sorry could not edit the comment

Comment: Please edit significant information into the question.  Comments have a 5-minute limit on editing.  As you noted, your question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a brute force approach collect pairs of points with their slope/intercept.

Then get the maximum size of the collected sets.

This approach is quadratic.

```js
function getAB([x1, y1], [x2, y2]) { // slope/intercept of y = ax + b
    var a;
    return x1 === x2
        ? [Infinity, x1]
        : [a = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1), y1 - a * x1];
}

var points = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [3, 2], [4, 2], [5, 1]],
    collection = {},
    usedPoints = new Set;

points.forEach((p1, i, a) => {
    if (usedPoints.has(p1.toString())) return;
    a.slice(i + 1).forEach((p2, j, b) => {
        if (usedPoints.has(p2.toString())) return;
        var key = JSON.stringify(getAB(p1, p2));
        collection[key] = collection[key] || new Set;
        collection[key].add(p1);
        collection[key].add(p2);
        usedPoints.add(p1.toString());
    });
});

console.log(Math.max(...Object.values(collection).map(s => s.size)));

console.log(Object.entries(collection).map(([k, v]) => [k, [...v].map(w => w.join(' '))]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Brute force is n^3. I don't think you can do better than n^2 to look at all the lines.

Comment: do you have a hint?

Comment: Yes it seems my code is still a bit more efficient since it is less the n^2. But thank you because I tried the brute force method and it was way less efficient than yours. So I think I can still learns something from this.

Also I'm correct that you calculate 4 and not 6?